# Mysql not selecting rows

Tags: php, mysql

OK, so I started playing with PDO since some ppl around here told me not to use mysql_query anymore, now I have another problem.

I started to change my other functions because some of my pages aren't showing any text any more, i have modified to PDO and this does not produce any text whatsoever:

```
$house_sq = $_GET['house_sq'];
$query = $db->prepare("select house_sq, house_address, house_po, house_city_id from houses_info where house_sq=$house_sq");
$query->execute(array($house_sq => $house_sq));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rows);
```

doesn't matter what number is there, is now showing anything, it works with mysql_query ...

Comment: Can we see the part that sets up $db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have to bind the value `:house_sq`

```
$query = $db->prepare("select house_sq, house_address, house_po, house_city_id from houses_info where house_sq=:house_sq");
$query->execute(array(':house_sq' => $house_sq));
```

Comment: it still doesn't show up anything :( if this is that hard i will get back to mysql

Comment: your connection is setup? did you add the named placeholder at the end of your `$db->prepare` ? `:where house_sq=:house_sq` ?

Comment: @user1642439 Update your question with the modifications so we can check them. And I really don't suggest you go back to the mysql_ functions

Comment: aaaa, now I get it, it shows my array, thank you, omg, thank you